# RxJava: Is it possible to avoid toBlocking().single()?

Tags: java, rx-java

I sometimes use RxJava to write in a more functional style for some complex filterings, mappings and so on (I know that this is not what it's made for, and I would be happy to use Kotlin or Java 8 for that, but I can't (I'm on Android so, stuck to 6).

However, when you try to "extract" the actual objects out of the Observable, you always need to write `.toList().toBlocking().singe()`

E.g. (not so complex, but you get the idea):

```
final List<CashRegister> cashRegisters = cashRegisterData.getCashRegisters();

return Observable.from(cashRegisters)
        .map(CashRegister::getName)
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
```

As you can see, "converting" the Observable into a list needs more lines than the actual mapping I want to perform.

Is there a way of doing this without the `toList().toBlocking().single()` chain?

Comment: *I would be happy to use Kotlin or Java 8 for that, but I can't*: you **are** using Java 8 already. So just use `cashRegisters.stream().map(CashRegister::getName).collect(toList())`

Comment: @JBNizet oh sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm on android and I'm using retrolambda for the `::` and lambdas

Comment: @JBNizet thanks again for your input. I didn't want to add another library (since it's not _really_ necessary) otherwise I would probably use streams backport for android.

Comment: I'll probably just write a static method

Comment: @JBNizet Guava has a ridiculous method count, so it's not recommended for Android (65536 method limit sucks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IxJava](https://github.com/akarnokd/ixjava) to perform the same operation:

```
final List<CashRegister> cashRegisters = cashRegisterData.getCashRegisters();

return ix.Ix.from(cashRegisters)
    .map(CashRegister::getName)
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

With RxJava one has to change the way they think about using `Observable`s.
The observable operation chain should be treated more like a math formula, not a sequence of operations. So, instead of trying to get results out of observable, try to figure out what you want to do with that list.

In RxJava, prefer not to `extract` the observable values, but to `subscribe` to them:

```
someObservable.subscribe(result -> {
    // Now do your deed with the result
    // for example:
    someAdapter.setData(result);
    someAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
})
```

I'd kindly recommend to read the documentation on [How to use RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/How-To-Use-RxJava#how-to-design-using-rxjava) to understand the idea.

Comment: I do understand how Rx works and how I'm supposed to use it. But there are a lot of APIs that are not reactive.

Comment: @Lovis I see. Maybe you could use `Observable.create` and  `Observable.defer` to make them reactive :)

Comment: Some APIs in Android require a return value. How do you wrap such an API into an observable? I can't get my head around that.